# Insert variable into file path string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Depending on the user selection the variable "team" contains different team names as string. I want then display the according team logos which are saved as .png files. Therefor I want to insert the variable's string into the file path. How to do that?

Thank you.

JS:

```
 $('ul.subbar li a').on('click', function(e) { // User clicks on a team in the navbar
  e.preventDefault(); // Stop loading new link
  var team = $(this).html(); //assign clicked team name to variable
  console.log(team);

$('.selectedClub').html(team);
$('.teamLogo').src("'images/Clubs/Germany/' + 'team' + '.png'").alt(team);
});
```

html:

```
      <div class="topRow">
        <div class="team">
          <div class="teamLogo">
            <img class="teamLogo" src="images/man united.png" alt="Manchester United">
          </div>
          <div class="selectedClub">Manchester United</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: fix the quotes: `.src("'images/Clubs/Germany/" + team + ".png'").alt(team);`

Comment: having the following error now: dashboard.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).src is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (dashboard.js:9)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: because `.src()` is not a jQuery function... you should use `$('.teamLogo')[0].src = imagePath.png` or better: `$('.teamLogo').attr('src', imagePath.png)`

Comment: and `.alt()` is not a function too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem here:

```
$('.teamLogo').src("'images/Clubs/Germany/' + 'team' + '.png'").alt(team);
```

Should probably be something like:

```
$('.teamLogo').attr('src', 'images/Clubs/Germany/' + team + '.png').alt(team);
```

(without the extra quotes)

Comment: tried the bottom solution, but now i get a no function error for the src part: dashboard.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).src is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (dashboard.js:9)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Ah I see. It's not `.src(`, it should be `.attr('src', 'images...`

Answer (score 0):

Better answer is to use string interpolation

```
$('.teamLogo').src(`images/Clubs/Germany/${team}.png`).alt(team);
```